# Plugin updated pushed with git break site

Tags: plugins, updates, git, vagrant

I'm having some trouble updating the plugins on a wordpress website. It's all my fault for waiting too long to update them, and now pushing the updates with git breaks the site (the development site is ok, only the staging site that I've pushed to breaks). I tried updating everything manually, and will composer, but both methods don't last - the plugins revert back to their previous version with subsequent git pushes.

Is there any way to update these plugins now, barring deleting them all and starting again (which I'm not entirely opposed to at this point). The site doesn't get too much traffic, but solutions with minimal downtime are preferable.

This is the error I'm seeing on the broken site:

"The site is experiencing technical difficulties. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions."

Here's the error from the terminal:

```
PHP Warning:
include_once(/srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins
/ajax-load-more/core/classes/class.alm-woocommerce.php): failed to open
stream: No such file or directory in
/srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-
more/ajax-load-more.php on line 258
Warning:
include_once(/srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins
/ajax-load-more/core/classes/class.alm-woocommerce.php): failed to open
stream: No such file or directory in
/srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-
more/ajax-load-more.php on line 258
PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening
'/srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-
more/core/classes/class.alm-woocommerce.php' for inclusion
(include_path='phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-token-
stream:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-
objects:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage:phar:///usr/bin/w
p/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/usr/share/
php') in /srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins
/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 258
Warning: include_once(): Failed opening
'/srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-
more/core/classes/class.alm-woocommerce.php' for inclusion
(include_path='phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-token-
stream:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-
objects:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage:phar:///usr/bin/w
p/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/usr/share/
php') in /srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins
/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 258
PHP Warning:
include_once(/srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins
/ajax-load-more/core/integration/elementor/elementor.php): failed to open
stream: No such file or directory in
/srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-
more/ajax-load-more.php on line 262
Warning:
include_once(/srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins
/ajax-load-more/core/integration/elementor/elementor.php): failed to open
stream: No such file or directory in
/srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-
more/ajax-load-more.php on line 262
PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening
'/srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-
more/core/integration/elementor/elementor.php' for inclusion
(include_path='phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-token-
stream:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-
objects:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage:phar:///usr/bin/w
p/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/usr/share/
php') in /srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins
/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 262
Warning: include_once(): Failed opening
'/srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-
more/core/integration/elementor/elementor.php' for inclusion
(include_path='phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-token-
stream:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-
objects:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage:phar:///usr/bin/w
p/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/usr/share/
php') in /srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins
/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 262
fatal: [107.170.41.149]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": ["wp", "option", "get", "template_root"], "delta": "0:00:00.558022", "end": "2020-09-11 16:11:42.260885", "failed": true, "failed_when_result": true, "rc": 0, "start": "2020-09-11 16:11:41.702863", "stderr": "PHP Warning:  include_once(/srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/core/classes/class.alm-woocommerce.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 258\nWarning: include_once(/srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/core/classes/class.alm-woocommerce.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 258\nPHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening '/srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/core/classes/class.alm-woocommerce.php' for inclusion (include_path='phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/usr/share/php') in /srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 258\nWarning: include_once(): Failed opening '/srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/core/classes/class.alm-woocommerce.php' for inclusion (include_path='phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/usr/share/php') in /srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 258\nPHP Warning:  include_once(/srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/core/integration/elementor/elementor.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 262\nWarning: include_once(/srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/core/integration/elementor/elementor.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 262\nPHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening '/srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/core/integration/elementor/elementor.php' for inclusion (include_path='phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/usr/share/php') in /srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 262\nWarning: include_once(): Failed opening '/srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/core/integration/elementor/elementor.php' for inclusion (include_path='phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/usr/share/php') in /srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 262", "stderr_lines": ["PHP Warning:  include_once(/srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/core/classes/class.alm-woocommerce.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 258", "Warning: include_once(/srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/core/classes/class.alm-woocommerce.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 258", "PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening '/srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/core/classes/class.alm-woocommerce.php' for inclusion (include_path='phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/usr/share/php') in /srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 258", "Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/core/classes/class.alm-woocommerce.php' for inclusion (include_path='phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/usr/share/php') in /srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 258", "PHP Warning:  include_once(/srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/core/integration/elementor/elementor.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 262", "Warning: include_once(/srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/core/integration/elementor/elementor.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 262", "PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening '/srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/core/integration/elementor/elementor.php' for inclusion (include_path='phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/usr/share/php') in /srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 262", "Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/core/integration/elementor/elementor.php' for inclusion (include_path='phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/usr/share/php') in /srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 262"], "stdout": "/themes", "stdout_lines": ["/themes"]}
```

(Yes, I know it's looking for a file it can't find.)

I'm using:
ansible 2.3
python version = 2.7.15rc1
PHP 7.2.19
vagrant 2.2.5

Let me know if there's any important information I forgot to include.

Edit: I should add that this may be a vagrant related issue. If there are any vagrant users out there, let me know what you think!

Comment: You need to contact the support route for the `ajax-load-more` plugin. It sounds like either they've broken their plugin on their git repo, you've not committed all the files needed, or an install/prep step has not been ran, such as initialising submodules or running a setup command such as `composer install`. The TLDR is that you use git to control the files for your plugins, and the current latest version of those git repos contains broken versions of the plugins. The fix is to update the repo with fixed versions

Comment: Note if it is a vagrant issue, it will be impossible to debug as you haven't shared the vagrantfile or any of the provisioners, but that would be offtopic on this site